# Change location of .terraform and terraform.tfstate directory when starting Terraform with path to main.tf file

Tags: terraform

When I start Terraform with `terraform apply ../myEnvironment/` it successfully takes the `main.tf` file in `../myEnvironment/main.tf` and creates a `terraform.tfstate` and a `.terraform` directory, but at the same time it creates a `.terraform` directory including a `terraform.tfstate` in the directory from where the Terraform command was executed.

Is there a way to say Terraform only create files and `.terraform` directory in the directory, where the main.tf file is located? so when executing `terraform apply ../myEnvironment/` only create files in `../myEnvironment/main.tf`?

I already included

```
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "../myEnvironment/terraform.tfstate"
   }
}
```

in my `main.tf`

Comment: I believe that after providers were split out from the main codebase in 0.10 that you kind of have to execute Terraform in the root module config directory to have clean behavior like you want.

Answer (score 10):

So I found the solution.

As mentioned [here](https://shinglyu.com/web/2019/04/06/switching-between-multiple-local-backend-in-terraform.html) you need to create the environment variable before starting Terraform:

```
TF_DATA_DIR=../myEnvironment/.terraform terraform init ../myEnvironment/
TF_DATA_DIR=../myEnvironment/.terraform terraform apply ../myEnvironment/
```

An answer mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_data_dir) specified the `terraform.tfstate` location in the `main.tf` file(s):

```
terraform {
  backend "local" { path = "../myEnvironment/terraform.tfstate" }
}
```

This way you are independent as to where you execute Terraform to do its magic. :)

Maybe it will help someone to save some time.